# Streaming Audio with OpenAL and FFMPEG

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, streaming, openal

Alright, basically I'm working on a simple video player and I'll probably be asking another question about lagging video\syncing to audio later, but for now I'm having a problem with audio. What I've managed to do to is go through all of the audio frames of a video and add them to a vector buffer then play the audio from that buffer using OpenAL.

This is inefficient and memory hogging and so I need to be able stream it using what I guess is called a rotating buffer. I've ran into problems, one being that there's not a lot of information on streaming with OpenAL let alone the proper way to decode audio with FFMPEG and pipe it to OpenAL. I'm even less comfortable using a vector for my buffer because I honestly have no idea how vectors work in C++, but I some how managed to pull something out of my head to make it work.

Currently I have a Video class that looks like this:

```
class Video
{
    public:
        Video(string MOV);
        ~Video();
        bool HasError();
        string GetError();
        void UpdateVideo();
        void RenderToQuad(float Width, float Height);
        void CleanTexture();
    private:
        string FileName;
        bool Error;
        int videoStream, audioStream, FrameFinished, ErrorLevel;
        AVPacket packet;
        AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
        AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx, *aCodecCtx;
        AVCodec *pCodec, *aCodec;
        AVFrame *pFrame, *pFrameRGB, *aFrame;

        GLuint VideoTexture;
        struct SwsContext* swsContext;

        ALint state;
        ALuint bufferID, sourceID;
        ALenum format;
        ALsizei freq;

        vector <uint8_t> bufferData;
};
```

The bottom private variables are the relevant ones. Currently I'm decoding audio in the class constructor to an AVFrame and adding the data to bufferData like so:

```
    av_init_packet(&packet);

    alGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
    alGenSources(1, &sourceID);

    alListener3f(AL_POSITION, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    int GotFrame = 0;

    freq = aCodecCtx->sample_rate;
    if (aCodecCtx->channels == 1)
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;
    else
        format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;

    while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
    {
        if (packet.stream_index == audioStream)
        {
            avcodec_decode_audio4(aCodecCtx, aFrame, &GotFrame, &packet);
            bufferData.insert(bufferData.end(), aFrame->data[0], aFrame->data[0] + aFrame->linesize[0]);
            av_free_packet(&packet);
        }
    }
    av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, audioStream, 0, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD);

    alBufferData(bufferID, format, &bufferData[0], static_cast<ALsizei>(bufferData.size()), freq);

    alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);
```

In my UpdateVideo() is where I'm decoding video to an OpenGL texture through the video stream, so it would make sense for me to decode my audio there and stream it:

```
void Video::UpdateVideo()
{
    alGetSourcei(sourceID, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    if (state != AL_PLAYING)
        alSourcePlay(sourceID);
    if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
    {
        if (packet.stream_index == videoStream)
        {
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &FrameFinished, &packet);
            if (FrameFinished)
            {
                sws_scale(swsContext, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                av_free_packet(&packet);
            }
        }
        else if (packet.stream_index == audioStream)
        {
            /*
            avcodec_decode_audio4(aCodecCtx, aFrame, &FrameFinishd, &packet);
            if (FrameFinished)
            {
                //Update Audio and rotate buffers here!
            }
            */
        }
        glGenTextures(1, &VideoTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, VideoTexture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, videoStream, 0, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD);
    }
}
```

So I guess the big question is how do I do it? I've got no clue. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need create OpenAL streamed sound source. Also you need pool of buffers for read you streamed data into and queue to play by OpenAL.

At open you need fill some buffers from pull and add their to source queue (alSourceQueueBuffers).
In update process you need unqueue already played buffers

```
int processed = 0;
ALuint bufID = 0;
// ...
alGetSourcei(source_handle, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &processed);
while (processed--) {
    alGetError();
    alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source_handle, 1, &bufID);
    // return buffId to buffers pool;
}
```

Then you need get empty buffer from pool and call your bufferData code with it buffer id.

in bufferData you don't need create source - pass it as parameter. Also you don't need to setup source parameters. Just queue existing buffer to existing Source. instead of alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID) you need use alSourceQueueBuffers(sourceID, 1, &bufferID)