# How to play FFMPEG sound sample with OpenAL?

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, openal

I am using FFMPEG to load Audio Video from File. It works with video, but I don't know how to play audio samples.

Here is my code to get audio samples:

```
m_AdotimeBase = (int64_t(m_Adocdec_ctx->time_base.num) * AV_TIME_BASE) / int64_t(m_Adocdec_ctx->time_base.den);   
if(!m_Adofmt_ctx)
{
    //AfxMessageBox(L"m_timeBase");
    return FALSE ;
}
int64_t seekAdoTarget = int64_t(m_currFrame) * m_AdotimeBase;   


if(av_seek_frame(m_Adofmt_ctx, -1, seekAdoTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY) < 0)
{
    /*CString st;
    st.Format(L"%d",m_currFrame);
    AfxMessageBox(L"av_seek_frame "+st);*/
    m_currFrame = m_totalFrames-1;
    return FALSE ;
}

if ((ret = av_read_frame(m_Adofmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
        return FALSE;
if (packet.stream_index == 0)       
{
    ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(m_Adocdec_ctx, &in_AdeoFrame, &got_frame, &packet);
    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

My problem is I want to listen that sample using OPENAL.

I would appreciate any tutorials or references on the subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Streaming Audio with OpenAL and FFMPEG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554409/streaming-audio-with-openal-and-ffmpeg)